# Cannot convert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to Excel when using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I a trying to write several numbers into an excel using openpyxl.
When i insert a single number it works fine (i.e my number gets inserted into the cell)

However when i try and insert an array to fill multiple cells it doesn't work.
i get an error saying "Cannot convert [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] to Excel"

the code that works to insert 1 number is:

```
mynumber = 8
ws.cell(column=ws.max_column, row=1, value=mynumber)
```

The code that doesn't work is:

```
myArray = [1,2,3,4,5]
ws.cell(column=ws.max_column, row=1, value=myArray)
```

Comment: Why do you think it should work? What should that cell look like?

Answer (score 0):

Using `str([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` woud work

Comment: Hi you are right this puts in the array as it is however i should have been more clear that i am trying to store a set of values across multiple cells.

Answer (score -1):

The answer.

```
for item in myArray:
    ws.cell(column=ws.max_column, row=1, value=item)
```